# ODI 12c Installation Issue

Tags: integration, etl, oracle-data-integrator

How can i install `Oracle Data Integrator` on `Non RDBMS` system? Is it possible to install `ODI` on `Non RDBMS` system?

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Data Integrator requires to install its repositories on an RDBMS. These repositories hold all the metadata about your connections, security, integration process and executions. With ODI 12.2.1.x releases, it supports Oracle database 11.2.0.4+, 12.1.0.1+, 12.2.0.1+, Microsoft SQL Server 2012 or 2014 and MySQL 5.6+ or 5.7+.

The ODI agents and ODI Studio can be installed on any machines, it doesn't need to have a local RDBMS. But it needs to be able to connect to the repositories.

It is possible to use ODI with sources and targets that are not RDBMS. For instance loading from a file to an Hive table.

**tl;dr : Only the repositories require an RDBMS.**